# Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Permission denied while opening file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

When trying to perform a simple query in BigQuery I am getting this error:

```
Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Permission denied while opening file.
```

I am using an IAM user with a BigQuery admin role. I can view the datasets and tables just not any data.

I have authorised the dataset too.

Comment: It's difficult to know without more info. Are your datasets external sources you don't have access to? Are you trying to import / export to a location you don't have access to? Can you add a sanitized version of the query you are running?

Answer (score 1):

You might be missing a storage permission. (storage.objects.get).
Try running  a gsutil -D [1](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp#options), check output for any 403 errors.

Answer (score 0):

Open your GCP console (Logs Explorer) and filter on the service you want (GCS here). It will give you the service account/account which need access + rights missing on the target ressource.

If you can recreate the error, do it and then refresh the log explorer.